# python subprocess.Popen with shell = False,

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

This command runs:

```
process_1     =  subprocess.Popen("gzip -dc " + infile + " > " + inter_file, 
                                  cwd                = base_dir,
                                  stdout             = subprocess.PIPE, 
                                  shell              = True,
                                  universal_newlines = True)
output, error = process_1.communicate()
```

Now, I want to remove `shell=True` (I have many lines like the above and 
I'm suspecting `Shell = True` causes a memory leak):

```
process_1     =  subprocess.Popen(["gzip", "-dc", infile, ">", inter_file], 
                                  cwd                = base_dir,
                                  stdout             = subprocess.PIPE, 
                                  shell              = False,
                                  universal_newlines = True)
output, error = process_1.communicate()
```

yields:

```
gzip:  > .gz: No such file or directory

gzip: blabla.txt: not in gzip format
```

but `blabla.txt` is `inter_file`: it seems that setting `Shell = False` confuses `infile` and `inter_file`. How to fix?

P.S. a general answer would be welcome. I have 50 odd system calls like the above that I need to reformat to run in `Shell = False` mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` is a [shell syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07) used for output redirection. Therefore it will be interpreted only when you run the command in a shell.

If you need to stick to the `-c` option for gzip, not zipping files in place, you can read the output in Python and write it to a file:

```
process_1     =  subprocess.Popen(["gzip", "-dc", infile], 
                                  cwd                = base_dir,
                                  stdout             = subprocess.PIPE, 
                                  shell              = False,
                                  universal_newlines = True)
output, error = process_1.communicate() 

with open(inter_file, 'wb') as file_desc:
    file_desc.write(output)
```

---

If you are sure you have enough disk space to have the original file twice on disk, at least for a moment, you can copy the file first and then run `gzip` without `-c`:

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(infile, inter_file)
process_1     =  subprocess.Popen(["gzip", "-d", inter_file], 
                                  cwd                = base_dir,
                                  stdout             = subprocess.PIPE, 
                                  shell              = False,
                                  universal_newlines = True)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to read the file in python. I just want the command to be executed. Is there no way to do this with Shell = False?

Comment: No, there isn't a way because `gzip` doesn't support to specify an output file other than the original input.file.gz. You disabled this by using `gzip -c`

Comment: PS: I've added a way which involves copying the file before zipping. This doesn't require to read the file in Python, but it's less efficient in terms of disk utilization.

Comment: Yes, I was moving along the same line. It's ok, in this case disk space is less important than speed.

Comment: Copying the file of course also takes time. I would benchmark this. I would be surprised if writing a file is slow in Python. (Note that you read it already by using `communicate()`)

Comment: I had not though of this. Do we need to communicate() in the first command?

Comment: If you don't care about the output, then no.  But make sure you check the exit_status of the `gzip` command to catch errors. In that sense, capturing stderror might be still useful

Comment: ok. Does this (that we don't need the output, speed is an issue) affect your first proposal?

Comment: Yes, of course, since output is needed in that example. But please don't follow your feelings for performance optimization, measure it!